# How to count character elements in a column with empty cells in R?

Tags: r, character, counting

I am new to R and have no experience with coding.
I have a data frame with a column named Type.2, which contain elements of the character category (i.e "grass", "poison", etc.), but also contains empty cells. I want to determine the total number of cells populated with a value (a word) in the column Type.2, like a sum. Thank you and I apologize in advance if the question is not clear.

Comment: How about `nrow(dplyr::filter(data, !is.na(Type.2)))`? Provided you mean NAs by empty cells.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I literally have empty cells, not marked as NA, so I do not know if it makes a difference. I use the code you posted and I got a "wrong" answer. It gave me the total number of cells, including those populated with characters and empty ones.

Comment: you can change the code from above to `nrow(dplyr::filter(data, Type.2==""))` which then counts the empty cells.

Comment: Or even nrow(dplyr::filter(data, !stringr::str_detect(Type.2, "[:alnum:]")))